# Extracting words from a string in postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

I am brand new to 'postgres' and trying to extract a value from a string. I'm trying to use a combination of `regexp_substr` and `replace` to implement the desired outcome.

UPDATED Example: I have a string `"When Harry met Sally"` (following the pattern, `When X met Y`).  I'd like to extract the word `Harry`, which is X.

I am trying the syntax: 
`regexp_substr(REPLACE('When Harry met Sally', 'When ', ''),' met [^.]*');` but am receiving the error message: `ERROR: function regexp_substr(text, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Can anyone help? I imagine that this is child's play for some pro out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using some function, check into the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) about its syntax... or if it exists.

*regexp_substr* does not exist in Postgresql. What are you trying to do ?

> I'd like to extract the word Harry.

By which criteria? The second word? The X in "When X met Y"?
Without more info, it's impossible to answer.

```
postgres=# select regexp_replace('When Harry met Sally', 
         'When (.*) met.*',
         '\1' );
 regexp_replace
----------------
 Harry
(1 row)
```

This is just an example. It could be wrong if, for example you want to support other kind of blank space, or be case sensitive, or admit some content before 'When', or...

Comment: You hit the nail on the head in terms of me looking for the X in "When X met Y", and I will update my question to more accurately reflect this. Thanks for the feedback!